# Fiat 500 Sunroof would not open. Re-calibrated it and now the motor makes a loud grounding sound

Tags: sunroof

I followed the re-calibration procedure outlined [here](http://hanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50407/fiat-500-sunroof-will-not-close/73512#73512) and the sunroof motor now makes a loud grinding sound but still will not open.

It sounds like the motor may be loose inside, as well.

It seems to bounce around when I'm driving, and I can feel it beneath the felt roof panel. It feels like it is sitting there.

I'd like to open it up and look and see if the motor assembly has, in fact, come loose.

Maybe it just needs to be realigned and fastened to the mounts, but I can't seem to find any resources on how to access, repair or replace the sunroof motor online anywhere.

Suggestions? Links? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.